# How can I turn the output into a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I am new to python, just wonder how can I turn `searchresult` into a list:
for example,
the `searchresult` is string output:

```
1234567
1234566
1234555
```

How can I convert it into a list?

```
   searchresult=("" + a['href'][1:-5][-7:])
    l=[]
    for i in searchresult:
        l.append(searchresult())
        print (l)
```

The above code returns a result with 'str' object is not callable

Comment: `searchresult = searchresult.split()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` Also I assume you want the list to be of integers. For that you can use `map`

```
output = "1234567 1234566 1234555"
lst = list(map(int,output.split()))
```

output

```
[1234567, 1234566, 1234555]
```

Comment: the output is dynamic the result now is [1234567] , [1234566], [1234555], i want it to be [1234567, 1234566, 1234555]

Comment: No it is not. My output is `[1234567, 1234566, 1234555]`

Comment: The output you said it shows is not even a really datatype. That isn't a list.

Comment: Can you take a look at my screen capture here https://pasteboard.co/K1DJNVk.jpg

Comment: Yeah, ofcourse that's happening. You need to append every output you are getting to a list. Right now you are trying to convert 1 into [1]

Comment: sorry, how can i append every output into a list i tried to append but becomes this https://pasteboard.co/K1DN9BA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the code on https://pasteboard.co/K1DJNVk.jpg
Based on the code provided in the link I'd like to walk you through what @BuddyBob said.

your code is as follows:

```
for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print ("" + a['href'][1:-5][-7:])
        searchresult=("" + a['href'][1:-5][-7:])
        lst=list(map(int,output.split()))
        print(lst)
```

To get the desired output you can change the code to following (I have commented the changes) -

```
temp=[] # lets declare a temporary array
output=[] # lets declare another array to hold the output data
for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print ("" + a['href'][1:-5][-7:])
        searchresult=("" + a['href'][1:-5][-7:])
        lst=list(map(int,output.split()))
        temp.append(lst) # I have replaced print(lst) with this statement
[[output.append(j) for j in i] for i in temp] # This removes any sublists 
print(output) # Voila ! The desired output
```